# Augmented Lagrangian for ADMM with two sets of constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I need to use ADMM algorithm to minimize a function of the form

$$f(x,\theta)+g(z,\eta)$$

subject to:

$$x-z=0$$
$$\theta-\eta=0$$

where $x,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\theta,\eta$ are positive scalar coefficients. How do I formulate augmented Lagrangian for this problem?

Comment: hint: consider the functions/constraints to be defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: Why not solve the equivalent problem $\min_{x,\theta} f(x,\theta) + g(x,\theta)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good hint was given by @LinAlg. I give here the expression of the augmented Lagrangian, but you should definitely follow that hint to obtain the result:
$$L_\rho(x,\theta,z,\eta,\lambda,\mu) = f(x,\theta)+g(z,\eta) + \lambda^\top(x -z) + \mu(\theta-\eta) + \frac{\rho}{2}\|x-z\|^2 + \frac{\rho}{2}(\theta - \eta)^2.$$